# Spring @PostMapping force null values for formdata urlencode?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test(TestFilter test) {
       System.out.println(test.id != null);         //true
       System.out.println(test.origin == null);      //false
       System.out.println(test.destination == null); //false
    }
}

public class TestFilter {
    public String id;
    public String origin;
    public String destination;
}
```

When I run the following request, the values in my received object are not `null`, but `""` empty:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'id=1' \
--data-urlencode 'origin=' \
--data-urlencode 'destination='
```

Question: how can I tell `Spring` to not add empty values on Strings, but keep them `null`?

Comment: `null` means not present, while `""` means it was present without value. You can change this by registering the `StringTrimmerEditor` for `String` (you can do this globally) and set this to convert to `null` instead of `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could solve it as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class StringTrimAdvice {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }
}
```

This converts any empty strings to nulls.

Comment: `PaginationController` is a bit of a strange name for an `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: Sorry, copy paste typo.